# Side spacing inside laundry bay

Tags: framing, dryer, washing-machine

I'm making a stacked laundry bay and would like it to be as narrow as possible. Are there minimum spacing requirements for the sides of the stack? I would like 2" each side between the machines and the wall. Any reason to give it more?

I will have service panel entrances on each side of the bay to reach for every hookup so I won't need to get behind the stack from the up front once they are placed inside. And there will be no door to the bay, just a curtain hanging from the ceiling.

Comment: We did this recently and it turned out that the door opening size is the critical factor in order to: 1) get the unit in the space, and 2) be able to open the dryer door. We used a bi-fold door and I think we should have used a swing door.

Comment: There will be no door, just curtain. Updated

Comment: Don't paint yourself into a corner by building only for a narrow machine.  10 years down the road you could find that narrow machines have fallen out of vogue and the smallest one you can find (*or would want, given its features)* is 100mm wider.

Comment: Also, are you aware of the new trend in the deluxe market toward single units which are both washer and dryer?  Not pre-stacked, I mean one machine the form-factor of a front load washer, which can blow hot air through the tumbler after the wash cycle... put dirty clothes in, take clean dry clothes out.  Seriously.  They're all the rage in tiny homes.  The units are front-load, so all the space above them is free.

Comment: I'm tight on space in an astronomical $ per square ft market...

Answer (score 1):

Download the installation manual for the machines you're getting and it should give you all the details.